# Unable to connect SQL database from CodeIgniter with sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have installed Xampp and Codeigniter. Now I want to connect to a SQL database. I have installed the sqlsrv drivers on Xampp, so that works. I also fixed a bug in the sqlsrv_driver.php and changed this:

```
function db_pconnect()
{
    // $this->db_connect(TRUE); original
    return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
}
```

This is my config file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'ipAddress\instanceName';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I have the following error:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 124

I had some errors with sqlsrv before, but I solved it by the answers on this question:

[Connect sqlsrv in Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831500/connect-sqlsrv-in-xampp/22831657#22831657)

Comment: Answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831500/connect-sqlsrv-in-xampp/22831657#22831657

Comment: I wouldn't even use codeigniter.  As we speak right now I'm having to add a feature to a codeigniter project and I

Comment: Why shouldn't I use CodeIgniter? It is an existing project, so I don't have a choice.

Comment: You can use Codeingiter for SQL connect but your webserver do need an SQL driver..

Comment: CodeIgniter is outdated. You'd better use Laravel. ;)

Answer (score 1):

there is an error with your hostname 
try to use

```
$db['development_local']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```