# PHP error connecting to MS SQL 2005 using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-server-2005, database-connection

I'm encountering an error every time I'm connecting to my MS SQL 2005 database using CodeIgniter framework, I'm using **PHP 5.6.8** version.`

> **"Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_website\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php
>   on line 76"**

I've already added dll files **php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll** and **php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll** to ext folder and on my php.ini, and installed **Microsoft SQL Native Client 2012**, 
this is my code in the sqlsrv_driver.php line 76 -> `return sqlsrv_connect($this->hostname, $connection);`

I already setup and installed all needed files but still I encounter this error, and **NO sqlsrv in phpinfo()**, so I created a sample php file to test if I will connect to my database w/out using a framework and its successfully connected in MS SQL database, However it doesn't if I used codeigniter.

Did I miss some code, configuration or software to install? Thanks for usual support!

This is my **database.php**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'MY-PC\MSSQL2005';
$db['default']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'MYDB';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: First check that the extension is install in `phpinfo()`; (something like`sqlsrv` should appear).

Comment: Sir, no sqlsrv in phpinfo()

Comment: it means you need to install `sqlsrv`

Comment: I already installed the needed file, but still it's not reflecting in phpinfo()

Comment: have to restart you apache ??

Comment: yes sir, I also restart my laptop.

Comment: no you have to restart you apache server

Comment: yes sir the apache in xampp control panel

Comment: have sqlsrv appear in you php info??

Comment: that's the weird thing, I already added all the dll file but still no sqlsrv in phpinfo()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect sqlsrv in Xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831500/connect-sqlsrv-in-xampp)

Comment: sir, has been done but its not working