# Connect to SQL Server using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am fairly new to using PHP. I downloaded XAMPP, and installed everything. PHP 5.5.27 is the version. I ran a test php program which was jsut echo "Hello World". It worked fine. I also was able to connect to MYSQL database using PHP.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "u/n", "pass", "databasename";
```

Problem i am having and need help is with connecting to sql server. How do i do that? I saw an example online and tried it:

```
$serverName = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"="name", "UID"=>"U/N", "PWD"=>"pass";>
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

But everytime i run this it tells me:

> Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: I think the SQL server PHP extension is not enabled in XAMPP.

Comment: ^^ Check the output from `php -m` to get installed modules.  It would appear that you either don't have it installed or not enabled. The `sqlsrv` extension does not ship with PHP.

Comment: The installation instructions: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

Comment: You have to install the sqlsrv extension if it still exists for php 5.5. Alternatives are odbc and pdo_odbc.

Comment: I recommend to use PHP's PDO library.

Comment: So, I went to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 and downloaded SQLSRV32.exe. When i ran the software it asks me to place location where the file are to be extracted, and i extracted them to C:\xampp\php\ext. I restarted my machine and still the same error. Did i do this right, if not what else?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831500/connect-sqlsrv-in-xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using PHP's Data Objects ([PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)) to connect to SQL Server (in fact you can use it to connect to MySQL or any other database).

Using the [MSSQL sqlsrv API](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) (various dlls must be set):

```
<?php

$server = 'servername';
$database = 'databasename';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'pass';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", 
                     $user, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Using the [ODBC Driver or DSN API](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) (requiring MSSQL ODBC Driver installed which usually ships with database or Windows in general):

```
<?php

$server = 'servername';
$database = 'databasename';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'pass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;           
                   database=$database",$username,$password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I ran the bottom example of your code (ODBC driver). ODBC driver is installed. But when i ran your code, it said "could not find driver". How can fix that?

Comment: I think this might help in helping me, so i ran phpInfo(), and on the page that opened up I went all the way down to PDO. PDO drivers that were enabled were mysql, and sqlite. How come others are not enabled?

Comment: In your php.ini file, uncomment the extension: `php_pdo_odbc.dll`. This might require restarting your web server.

Comment: I went a different route. For future is someone else ever comes to this post this is what i did to succed. http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html