# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to connect to microsoft sql express using php in my local machine ubuntu, the databse is in the server cloud, but I got this error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Filename: sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php

Line Number: 144

Backtrace:
```

I'm using codeigniter framework, I've tried to search the solution but its not working for me on ubuntu, and only finding the solution for windows,

Is it possible to resolve this problem on my ubuntu 14.04, instead of switching Operating System?

NOTE : I'm using LAMP (XAMPP) in my local environment.

Comment: your question same as "how can setup my android phone run iOS application". :(

Comment: so the answer is this cannot be done ya? Ohhhh

Comment: Can't. https://www.quora.com/How-would-one-install-Microsoft-SQL-Server-on-Ubuntu

Comment: okay thank you fast comment and sharing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Finally After several years Now Microsoft had launch the sql server for Linux : you can find more about this in this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup

NOTE :  I wish they could have done it before I was working on some project that depends on sql-server.

**OLD** 
It looks like this is not possible to setup in ubuntu, for someone out there have same problem switching Operating system to Windows is the best choice for now.

Comment: it looks like it, you need to use Windows to use it.

Comment: Now we can install it on Ubuntu :D

Answer (score -1):

You  need to download the driver and must do couple of settings.

Have a look

[Connect sqlsrv in Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831500/connect-sqlsrv-in-xampp)

Comment: is this for windows or ubuntu?

Comment: I think its not for ubuntu, its for windows